# How can I set template variables from my middleware or session variable?

Tags: go

I'm curious as to how I would set a template variable from a piece of middleware I have, this is my middleware:

```
func IsUserLoggedIn(router http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                log.Println("Checking if user is logged in")

                session, err := store.Get(r, "loggedIn")
                if err != nil {
                        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
                        return
                }

                // Perform some If Statements and set True/False
                // Set Session Variables
                session.Values["isLoggedIn"] = true

                // Save Session
                session.Save(r, w)

                // Set Template Variable
                router.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
}
```

Then in my template for my main layout:

```
{{ define "layout" }}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <title> {{ .Title }} </title>

  </head>
  <body>

    {{ SET SOMETHING HERE TO SAY YOU'RE LOGGED IN }}
    {{ GET THE SESSION VARIABLE AND SET ACCORDINGLY }}

    {{ template "body" .}}


  </body>

</html>


{{ end }}
```

Basically how can I access a session variable inside my template?

Comment: I would say to create a application level function, that can be accessed from anywhere, and in the application just  return `store.Get(r, "loggedIn")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I did for my personal website was to add a `Session` helper available in my templates, and in this helper retrieve the session of the current request then check and return the requested key.

Something like that:

```
func render(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, name string, data interface{}) {
    t, err := template.New(name).Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "Session": func(name string) interface{} {
            return sessions.GetSession(r).Get(name)
        },
    }).ParseFiles(...)
}
```

You can see the full version here: [app/render.go](https://github.com/elwinar/elwinar/blob/master/app/render.go)

Comment: This is fantastic! Quick question thugh, why do you return "Session" as type `interface{}`? Fairly new to golang and don't quite understand `interface{}` is it just a generic thing?

Comment: `interface{}` is the standard go way of meaning `any type`. It has it up and down sides. The point here is that my session store is basically a map with  `strings` as keys and `interface{}` as value, so I can put a boolean for the logged state, a string for the username, etc. And the `Session` helper return just that.

Comment: I asked another question over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987769/interface-struct-does-not-implement-x-wrong-type-or-method-not-sure-why-i-am if you are able to help out with your awesome Go knowledge!